# Facebook API: Login only for API ID owner

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-login

I try to build a web application that, through it, I can publish post on Facebook.

Problems come out when i wanna log the user without showing login popup, but only insert text and send message, without that nuisance.

But the login popup it's useful for provide use of my app to all user Facebook.

This app it's exclusive for one person, so i don't need that all user Facebook use my app. So I thought a login in function only for API ID/KEY owner

It's possible?

Comment: you can make it for one or for all, which one do you want?

Comment: For one, but main problems it's other: i don't wanna insert user and pass in login popup, anytime, but only write and send

Comment: if you know the credentials ahead of time you can post to FB from a server or using something like tumblr->ifttt->FB. if it's all client-side, i suspect you will need the user to manually enter the "oAuth" info themselves.

Comment: not necessary all client-side. However i know the credential ahead, and i don't want use the "oAuth"